# Get info a field of a page with javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i need to get an information of another page with javascript or jquery, to show that field on another page

the id of the field is "profile_field_13_1" and it shows the member status
I would like to get that "status" to put in an html page, how can i do that?
I already tried this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){if(jQuery('#profile-advanced-right').length){
var status=jQuery('.middleline #profile_field_13_1 dd div:eq(0)').html();
<div class="status"><span id="cs">'+status+'</span></div>
');
}});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is where you can use ajax.

```
var url = "mypage.html";

$.get(url,function(data){
   var contentFromTheOtherPage = data;
   //process it here
});
```

Comment: Didn't work :/ i'm starting with javascript and jquery, can you make it a little easy?

Comment: Thanks! gonna take a look